# Find all files with exactly n lines

Tags: bash, shell

I solved the said question writing a small script `has_n_lines.sh` which receives `n` as a parameter (in this case its a specific set of `txt` files):

```
#!/bin/bash

files=`find . -name "*.txt"`

for file in $files
do
    nlines=`wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1`
    if [ "$nlines" -eq "$1" ]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Is there any simpler way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, something like this should do the trick

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'wc -l < "$1"' -- {} \;
```

What this does is is of course finds all `.txt` files. Then it executes `wc -l` by sending in file by file (`<` sends in, `{}` uses file by file). `\;` denotes where `-exec` ends. By sending in filename via `<` makes `wc -l` output only the number of lines. Now you can introduce comparison via:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c '(($(wc -l < "$1") == $n)) && echo "$1"' -- {} \;
```

where `$n` is the number of lines you want.

> **Explanation (thanks to [John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman))**: Redirections (`<`) or `if` statements cannot be used directly with `find ... -exec`. This means that you need to explicitly invoke a subshell, inside which you can use them. For extra safety, `--` is `$0` and `{}` is `$1`, the latter is used in subshell. This ensures that filenames containing whitespaces are handled correctly.
>
> Also you need to `export $n` prior to invoking above command, because a subshell cannot access `$n`. So if you run `bash has_n_lines.sh 123`, where `123` is the desired number of lines, prepend this to `has_n_lines.sh`: `n=$1 && export $n;`.

Answer (score 0):

or without a trick:

```
vocabulary_cpp ❱ wc -l `find . -name '*.txt'`
    24 ./iterator_01.txt
   707 ./iterator_01_longman.txt
  3122 ./algorithm_now_word.txt
   113 ./list.txt
  3966 total
vocabulary_cpp ❱ wc -l `find . -name '*.txt'` | grep -P "^ +24"
    24 ./iterator_01.txt
vocabulary_cpp ❱
```

thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
wc -l `find . -name '*.txt'` | grep -P "^ +$1"
```

and:

```
vocabulary_cpp ❱ ./test.sh 24
    24 ./iterator_01.txt
vocabulary_cpp ❱
```

Comment: Following your logic, if I did `(...) | grep 1` I would incorrectly get as results `./iterator_01.txt` and `/iterator_01_longman.txt`

Comment: @Camandros Thanks you are right. It was fixed. Just by adding `regex` to match the beginning of the line.